# No authorized_hosts file created

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, keys

I want to log in without having to enter a password. I have explored my options and generated keys. The next step mentioned is to copy the file contents to authorized_host file. But that file does not exist in my case. I am connecting to a prompt issued by a local daemon. So basically I am connecting to localhost.

Comment: Why are you using ssh to connect to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create it ;)

If you're on linux you can use:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your case?

If you want to connect to remote server using public key, you must creat a pair of key, one store on your local machine, is private key. Then you must copy public key to remote server, use ssh-keygen to generate content of authorized_keys file:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f publickey.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then try to connect to remote host.

Comment: I get 'uudecode failed' error message

Comment: Case: I want to ssh to localhost without having to give password

Comment: You only do the same task above, but in your local machine, not in remote host.

Answer (score 0):

`.ssh/authorized_hosts` is the wrong file name.

`.ssh/authorized_keys` is the file you should be creating.